# How to set up a Mobile WebAutomation App with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, kivy

Ok, I'm new with python and kivy and all that... I've seen some automation scripts using Selenium python, but they're all in a computer, I had an idea of building an android App using kivy that will automate a task in the internet but I haven't found any clues on how to make selenium work on an Android... Some help?

Comment: Take a look at the Appium documentation here: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#setup-for-an-ios-real-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/) and/or [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop)
2. Install [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio)
3. Validate the installation using [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor)
4. Install [Appium-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/) using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

   ```
   pip install Appium-Python-Client
   ```
5. Now you should be ready to automate your application using Python, the minimal code would be:

   ```
   from appium import webdriver

   desired_caps = {}
   desired_caps['platformName'] = 'android'
   desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'emulator-5554' #replate it with your emulator or deal device name
   desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = '300'
   desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'your.application.package'
   desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'your.application.activity'
   desired_caps['automationName'] = 'uiautomator2'

   driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
   driver.find_element_by_id("some element ID").click()
   ```

More information including sample projects: [Appium - Code Examples - Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Python)